# Panel allocation on CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a 80% screen of the google map (bottom) and 20% screen of a div id (called #data) for the top. The below does not seem to work. The amended are marked ** and end with **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        **#map-canvas { height: 80% }
        #data { height: 20% }**
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    **<div id="data"/>**
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Define *not working*... Did you update the details in the request for the Google Maps API? `div` elements are not self-closing.

Comment: Hi guys, the div elements are not the problem. I've tried them with and without.

Comment: What i want, is to have 20% of the screen on top and 80% of the screen below. Top portion will show data and the bottom portion will show the map.

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it does or doesn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your body a height in em e.g. 100em; or better still wrap your 2 divs in a parent div and give that a height in em's or px. This will then give your divs a context of what 80% and 20% means. Also, you're asking for trouble by giving the div's a self close. This is not legitimate mark-up. You may find it works in some browsers, but it's unlikely to work in all, and even if it does, it might not in the future. It's likely to break.